# JsonResult method is not working/loading

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am doing [this](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2014/05/how-to-retrieve-database-data-show-using-jquery-mvc-asp.html) tutorial.

In my controller class I have my

```
 public JsonResult GetAllUser(){
    List<database1> allUser = new List<database1>();

    using (dbContext1 dc = new dbContext1 ())
        {
            allUser = dc.database1.ToList();
        }

    return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = allUser,
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
        };
    }

 public JsonResult GetUserWithSerialNumber(string prefix){
    List<database1> allUser = new List<database1>();

    using (dbContext1  dc = new dbContext1())
        {
            allUser = dc.database1.Where(a => a.SerialNumber.Equals(prefix)).ToList();
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = allUser, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

As of right now, GetAllUser() does not work while get GetUserWithSerialNumber() returns what it is suppose to. Originally GetAllUser() worked, then it gave me

```
"The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property."
```

so I put "Int32.MaxValue" in the GetAllUser method and now when I run the webpage and click on the GetAllUser button it gives me

```
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.Script: http://localhost:54936/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:7017
```

All my other methods work except the GetAllUser(). My cshtml and other code looks exactly like the on in the tutorial so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please create [minimal complete verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also have you debugged `GetAllUser` method? why you are defining `MaxJsonLength ` what is the purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the only reason I get the script message is because my database is huge. It's taking too long to go through all of the entries, put them in a list, and put it as an object.